# Need help with creating an template of a PDF

Tags: templates, moderncv

I have found this PDF and thought it would be a great idea to make a template of it. I am not so good to LaTeX so it would be nice if you could help me. Here the link to the CV-document:

[Link to CV PDF](http://www.bewerbungsservice-aktiv.de/modules/wsShop/article.php?article_id=208786&location_id=125)

It's 4 boxes - three are colors and one is a picture. I know how to make a colored box:

```
\usepackage{framed, color}
 \colorbox{green}{Text}
```

But how did I get them in the right position, with the right color? And how did I get the image in this position? And how to get the green line in the left box? And should I use this to manipulate with the font size?

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{t1enc}
...
{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Foo}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont bar!}
```

{\Huge Foo}{\tiny bar!}

It would be great if you would help me with that. I will learn a lot of it and will be able to make such layouts in future. So please help the LaTeX-beginner :-)

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{framed, color}%to make boxes and colours

\usepackage{t1enc}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}%manipulate with font size

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
%\includegraphics[?????]{•}
%\end{figure}


\colorbox{grey}{Marie Muster}

\colorbox{grey}{\textsc{\textbf{Bewerbung}} als \textsc{\textbf{Assistentin}}\\ im \textbf{Bereich Biochemie}}

\colorbox{olive}{Am Musterweg 22\\
12345 Musterstadt\\
Telefon 0 25 06 / 12 34 56\\
E-mail: Marie.Muser@Provider.de}

\end{document}
```

The minimal example is really small - but that is because I am a new LaTeX user and have read a lot but don't understand so much.

I would be great with help but please don't use XeLaTeX or anything like that. I am just learning common LaTeX :-) ... and it would be nice if I could learn from this project (and when someone would help me).

Comment: Don't use `t1enc` as it is obsolete. Use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead. Please put the fragments of code you've posted together into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which provides people with the beginnings of the template you want to create so that they don't need to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point without `tikz` (hence no shading).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{framed, xcolor}%to make boxes and colours

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,fix-cm,kpfonts}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}%manipulate with font size

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent
\raisebox{-\fboxsep}{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr3in+2\fboxsep\relax,height=\dimexpr3in+2\fboxsep\relax]{example-image-a}}%
\colorbox{gray!50}{\parbox[b][3in][b]{3in}{\fontsize{30}{36}\bfseries\scshape\textcolor{green}{M}arie \textcolor{green}{M}uster}}%
\par
\vspace{-0.3ex}
\noindent
\colorbox{black!70}{\parbox[b][3in][b]{3in}{%
\raggedleft
\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\textsc{\LARGE Bewerbung}} als \textbf{\textsc{\LARGE Assistentin}}}\\
\textcolor{green}{\rule{2in}{0.5pt}}\\
\textcolor{white}{im \textbf{Bereich Biochemie}}
}}%
\colorbox{olive}{\parbox[b][3in][t]{3in}{%
\color{white}
Am Musterweg 22\\
12345 Musterstadt\\
Telefon 0 25 06 / 12 34 56\\
E-mail: Marie.Muser@Provider.de
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]